# Thread keeping a reference forever

Tags: java, android, memory-management

I have a class:

```
class RenderView implements Runnable {
   Thread renderThread;
   public void  run() {
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            //does some work
        }
} 

//At some point in executed code, inside RenderView class (i'm sure it's executed)
renderThread = new Thread (this);

//When activity is closed (also, i'm sure this part is executed)
renderThread.interrupt();
```

And the renderThread really stops (at least, the run() method quits).

But for some reason, there is still some reference to renderView in my code, after i exit the activity. This is causing me a huge memory leak.

And a hprof dump tells me: 
 java.lang.Thread (this one is in GC Root)
    has a reference to 
       target (mypackage.RenderView)

**I have no idea why this Thread class is keeping a reference to my Thread, even though i've already finished the Thread!** Any ideas?

**EDIT**: The renderView is referenced in, say, Activity B. So, when i exit the activity, no reference to renderThread should still be reachable. But still i tried setting renderThread = null : doesn't work. As i was able to find out via MAT Analyzer, **the only thing that keeps renderView from being Garbage Collected is this weir reference from java.lang.Thread.**

[image: MAT Analyzer Screenshot]

Comment: The solution in Android is don't manage the threads. Use AsyncTask on runOnUIThread should work for most anything.

Comment: But if you have found a special case where these won't work please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use an AsyncTask or runOnUIThread()?

I've never seen a need for what your doing.  Perhaps there is one but otherwise just use AsyncTask or runOnUIThread.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I didn't know i was reinventing the wheel... I'll take a look at this function. Thank you.

Comment: runOnUIThread is not well known. If this or AsyncTask works for you please mark the question as answered. Thanks

Comment: It's just that it's a little divergent to the question. I've seen the use of threads as i'm doing in some examples like Lunar Lander, in the sample provided together with the SDK 2.3. It's also gonna take me a while to reimplement the code using your suggestions. I've temporally just tried to lower my memory leak.
I thank you very much for the help. When i reimplement my code using your suggestion, if it solves the memory leak, i'll mark your answer as correct.
I just don't know if it'd be right to mark it right now. But thank you for the answer.

Comment: Thats the Lunar part of the Lander.

Answer (score 1):

Release your thread instance with

```
renderThread = null;
```

A thread instance is as any other instance, an object. Even if it finished running, you keep the reference to it, until you release it.

Comment: The problem is, i lost the reference to the activity that contains the renderView that contains the renderThread anyway, but still some weird reference is kept. See the Edit. I tried nullifying anyway (you never know), but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to nullify `renderThread`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, renderThread.interrupt may not stop the thread, it is just setting a flag and singnals JVM that it can be interrupted.That is why may be your thread is still running.The best practice is gracefully exit from run method by just setting a flag in the while loop.

```
    while(isRunning){

    }

// at some point, say 

    isRunning = false;
```

The best practices on Android UI design can be had from the following link.

[Android UI design pattern:](http://www.slideshare.net/mswolfson/android-ui-patterns)

Comment: Oh, i just use the interrupt the same way as this flag, as you can see in my code. I do a while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()). When you call renderThread.interrupt(), the thread does exit (i've tested it; code after the while is in fact reached).

Comment: @userEng15, may be it is exiting out of loop by doing this, but the thread is not stopping.That is why in your profiler, still it is visible.

Comment: renderThread.getState() shows "TERMINATED". How can it not be stopped if its run() has escaped? I had this as the definition of it being stopped.

Comment: Actually, android UI runs on single thread.So if you have any other functionalities, then you can use spawn a child thread.But implement it using best practices suggested by @Code Droid.